# how and why do training and cross validations sets wear out in time?

Tags: cross-validation

In google's crash course on [ML](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/validation/another-partition), I have read an interesting tip on train&validation sets.
they say

> 'Test sets and validation sets "wear out" with repeated use. That is,
> the more you use the same data to make decisions about hyperparameter
> settings or other model improvements, the less confidence you'll have
> that these results actually generalize to new, unseen data.
>
> If possible, it's a good idea to collect more data to "refresh" the
> test set and validation set. Starting anew is a great reset.

how is that possible? how and why should it wear out? And what does 'wearing out of the data' mean to begin with?' And can I solve this by randomly re-partitioning the sets into three(train-test-cv) for different models rather than using the same partitions for all?

Comment: your answers has solved my problem but I can neither upvote nore select it as the response since I am 4 reputation points short of doing these actions. So if you could like my question, maybe I will be closer to doing those. 
Thank you very much for your response by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of splitting our data into training, validation, and test sets is to evaluate our models with data that they have not seen before and to directly compare them (and to choose the best model based on that comparison).

However, the more we use the test and validation sets to compare models or choose hyperparameters, the more we are relying on them to choose models that perform the best on them, that is, our models begin to depend indirectly (through us selecting them) on the test set, therefore defeating their initial purpose of evaluating our models with data they have not seen before.

The problem with randomly re-partitioning the sets into different train/validation/test sets for each problem is that it does not enable you to directly compare the performance of the different models, therefore defeating the very purpose of having a test set.

A solution is proposed in the paragraph you cited:

> If possible, it's a good idea to collect more data to "refresh" the test set and validation set. Starting anew is a great reset.